# What do the car stats mean in Hot Wheels Stunt Track Driver?

Tags: hot-wheels-stunt-track-driver

In *Hot Wheels Stunt Track Driver*, cars have three stats represented by a tire, a car seat, and a steering wheel. What do the three car stats mean?

[image: Hot Wheels car selection screen]